# Physical state of the carbon denoted with "gr"

Tags: everyday-chemistry, notation

I would like to know what does a gr mean when used to represent the physical state of the carbon, for example, in the synthesis of the glucose

$$\ce{6C_{(gr)} + 6H2_{(g)} + 3O2_{(g)}-> C6H12O6_{(\ell)}} \quad,$$

what does the $\mathrm{gr}$ mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The letters in brackets indicate state of aggregation (includes state of matter, crystal structure (solids) and atomicity (gases)), therefore $\ce{C_{(gr)}}$ most likely refers to **graphite**. Often one can also see $\ce{C(s, gr)}$ or $\ce{C(s, graphite)}$ There is a nice demonstration in [1, p. 248]:

> $$\ce{C(gr) + O2(g) <=> CO2(g)}$$
>   Here $\ce{(g)}$ indicates that the compound is gas, [...], and $\ce{(gr)}$ that carbon is graphite (*not many people will burn diamonds, even if they are chemists*).

P. S. According to IUPAC recommendations, subscript notation is deprecated.

1. Metiu, H. *Physical Chemistry: Thermodynamics*; Garland Science, **2006**. ISBN 978-1-315-31491-4.